# Obtaining exact positions

Tags: fortran, output

I have a simple code written in standard FORTRAN 77 for numerically integrating equations of motion. The integration loop is the following

```
  yant=x0(2)
  DO i=1,n-1
    ti=t0+DBLE(i-1)*tstep
    t=ti
    CALL bstoer8(t,tstep,x,ndimf,ierr,derivs)
    IF(x(2)*yant.LT.0d0)THEN
      WRITE(52,'(7(F16.8))')t,x
    ENDIF  
    yant=x(2)
  ENDDO
```

The bstoer8 module contains the standard Bulirsh-Stoer integrator and it can be found [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/8tq7dc36ifirqpe/bstoer8.sub).

As we can see, I want to print, to an external data file, the time and all six vector elements (x, y, z, p_x, p_y, p_z) when y = 0.

However I do not get the exact times when y = 0. What I get is the closest time step. For example one of lines in the data file is the following

```
 -0.17000000     10.45572291      0.00264921     -0.83321521     -0.21271715     45.32160003     -1.24830046
```

We observe that y is very small (0.00264921) but not exactly equal to zero. Moreover the time t contains only two decimal digits because the time step of the numerical integration is equal to 0.01.

So, my question is the following: How can I obtain the exact times when y = 0? In other words, how can I have y equal to 0 (with eight decimal digits) and the corresponding time with eight decimal digits?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You will need to do some interpolation.

Comment: impossible to answer without knowing what `bstoer8` is doing.

Comment: @agentp Thank you for your reply. bstoer8 is the standard Bulirsh-Stoer integrator. Please see my edit.

Comment: depending on the level of accuracy you seek (nothing computational is "exact") you can interpolate or you can repeat the last time step iteratively. (or brute force just run the whole thing with a smaller time step)

Comment: @agentp Could you please provide a detailed answer with your suggestions? Repeating the last time step iteratively sounds very interesting. Bu how exactly can I achieve this?

Comment: Please don't post links to code at some file sharing service. If the code is important, put it directly as text inside the answer. If it is not important, don't show it  at all. In some cases, link to a public repository might be OK, but not a zipped file at some file sharing service, where it may get deleted at any time.

Comment: you would likely use a secant approach https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method to find your zero.  Its really beyond the scope of the site to do all that code development for you.  Try it and ask a new question if you get stuck.